# Sending optional parameters to Twilio Studio to trigger Flow using PHP SDK

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-studio

I'm trying to send optional parameters to a Twilio Studio Flow Trigger using PHP. I followed the example shown in the [Twilio Studio REST API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution#create-a-new-execution) and was successful triggering a new Flow using the (required) sender and recipient phone numbers.

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "my_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
$execution = $twilio->studio->v1->flows("FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                                ->executions
                                ->create("+15555559876", "+15555551234");
```

After getting the basic communications working, I now want to pass a couple parameters to the Flow. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any PHP examples that include optional parameters. (The docs mention how to access parameter values in the widgets with {{flow.data.parameterName}}, but not how to generate the request in PHP.)

The answer is probably easy and obvious but I can't figure it out and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Received an answer from Twilio Support.

```php
$data = ["parameters" => ["foo" => "bar"]];
$flow = $twilio->studio->v2->flows("FWxxxxx");
$flow->executions->create($to, $from, $data);
```

Optional parameters are now passing through and can be used by widgets in the Studio Flow.